# How do you import a user model with strongloop arc database discovery

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

The loopback application already comes equipped with a user model and CRUDs; however, I'm trying to hook an old database up to my loopback application that already contains a user model so the model discovery replies with:

```
ValidationError: The `ModelDefinition` instance is not valid. Details: `name` is not unique (value: "User").
at /home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:264:12
at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:483:13)
at ModelConstructor.next (/home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/hooks.js:75:12)
at done (/home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:480:25)
at /home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:554:7
at ModelConstructor.<anonymous> (/home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/validations.js:353:5)
at allCb (/home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/dao.js:1374:7)
at /home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/connectors/memory.js:371:7
at /home/theory/.nvm/versions/v0.12.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Can I rename the incoming model to something else using model discovery?  Is there a merge option for models?

Comment: Can you explain how did you get this error message?

Comment: Same thing here.. do u have any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using a exiting model name (User) which belongs to loopback. Calling the model something like "UserAuth" would work.

Using `slc arc` if connected to the database when changing the model name you can `migrate` the old model to the new model.

To read more on why and how read their documentation here:
[Using built-in models](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+built-in+models#Usingbuilt-inmodels-Usermodel)