# Why is loopback throwing the error: The `ModelDefinition` instance is not valid

Tags: node.js, express, model, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am taking [Strongloop](https://strongloop.com/) for a spin. I am just trying the "Getting Started" tutorials, and the basic functionality one would typically want/need.

I am using Windows and PostgresSQL, so I created a new datasource and edited the `model-config.json` to change the built-in models datasource to this new one, lets call it `lbdev`.

After that I followed the docs section about [creating the tables for the built-in models](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Creating+database+tables+for+built-in+models). The tables were created (everything looks fine in PgAdmin). I ran the explorer and the only public API (Users) is there, so far so good.

Next, using Arc I am trying to discover the models from the `lbdev` schema (with empty tables) but I get the following error for each table that is there:

> Oops! Something is wrong
>   The `ModelDefinition` instance is not valid.
>
> **Details**: `name` is not unique (value: "User").
>
> **Name**: ValidationError
>
> **Message**: The `ModelDefinition` instance is not valid. Details: `name` is not unique (value: "User").
>
> **Details**: {"context":"ModelDefinition","codes":{"name":["uniqueness"]},"messages":{"name":["is not unique"]}}
>
> **Request**: /workspace/api/DataSourceDefinitions/server.lbdev/createModel
>
> **status**: 422

It is like it has already been done, but the Models tree in Arc is empty.  Can someone shed some light over what is going on here?

**Note:** There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273114/how-do-you-import-a-user-model-with-strongloop-arc-database-discovery) with a similar problem but very little info is provided so I created a new one.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are trying to discover models on that schema... are there other tables that already existed? If so, then you want to only pull those in, and **not** the tables that were auto-created from the built-in LoopBack models. If you try to "discover" the models that you just generated the tables from, then you will naturally have duplicate models (they are built-in, they already exist).

Comment: That makes sense, but if I would like someone else to "manage" those models and they need to do it through the interface shouldn't it be possible to have the built-ins in the composer as well?

Comment: Nope, if you want to manage, extend, alter, whatever the built-in models then you need to create a new model and use whatever built-in model as the `base`.

Comment: thanks @jakerella, I guess this should either be closed or if you want to provide your comments as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I guess I can... it's not a terribly great answer. ;)

Comment: not a terribly great question either :) just trying to keep the house clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying my comments into an answer...

I'm not sure why you are trying to discover models on that schema... are there other tables that already existed? If so, then you want to only pull those in, and *not* the tables that were auto-created from the built-in LoopBack models. If you try to "discover" the models that you just generated the tables from, then you will naturally have duplicate models (they are built-in, they already exist).

If you want to manage, extend, alter, whatever the built-in models then you need to create a new model and use whatever built-in model as the base:

```
// common/models/visitor.json

{
  "name": "Visitor",
  "base": "User",
  // ... other options
  "properties": {
    // ... additional properties to those already on User
  },
  "acls": [
    // ... additional ACLs to those on User... careful, these might overwrite built-in restrictions!
  ],
  // ... other overwrites/additions
}
```